# How to target first and last elements of a class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I have this simple markup of a table:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__headers"></div>
  <div class="table__row"></div>
  <div class="table__row"></div>
</div>
```

And I've styled it using this CSS:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
}

.table {
    &__headers,
    &__row {
        @extend .grid;
        padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;

        :first-child {
            text-align: start;
        }

        :last-child {
            text-align: end;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    &__row {
        background: #f8f8fa;
    }
}
</style>
```

My only issue is that I'm not able to specifically target the **first** and **last** `table__row` elements so I can style them differently.

The following does not work:

```
&__row:first-of-type {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

&__row:last-of-type {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

`last-of-type` works but not first of type. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: Because that’s not how these pseudo classes work (as you have expected). An element has to match all conditions in order to be selected by the selector. Since `table__row` is never the first div in its parent, it will never match the `.table__row:first-of-type` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript solution:

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".table__row"); // Get all rows into an "array-like" object
rows[0].classList.add("firstRow");                   // Get and style first row
rows[rows.length-1].classList.add("lastRow");        // Get and style last row
```

```css
.firstRow { background-color:red; }
.lastRow { background-color:green; }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__headers"></div>
  <div class="table__row">blah</div>
  <div class="table__row">blah</div>
  <div class="table__row">blah</div>
  <div class="table__row">blah</div>
  <div class="table__row">blah</div>
  <div class="table__row">blah</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I was afraid it was going to come to this :(, there is no CSS only solution (asking for a friend).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `:first-of-type` is not working is because it's the functional equivalent of `:nth-child(1)`, when what you need is `:nth-child(2)` due to the preceding `<div>` element.

These selectors are intended to work using elements (TagName) and not classes.

Comment: But while it's easy to know what number the first row will be (2), the last is not so easy if the table isn't static.

Comment: It's not necessary to know the last number. `:last-of-type` works well in this situation.